# Tumblr code every entry post?

Tags: tumblr

I don't know why Tumblr code is generated every entry post. My code seems fine.

My page: http://paintloop.com.ar

My tumblr theme code: http://pastebin.com/iMd4vG5H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing, it seems the theme is missing a closing `{/block:Posts}` theme operator:

```
{block:IfEndlessScroll}
<div class="autopagerize_page_element">
{/block:IfEndlessScroll}

  {block:Posts}

  {block:Photo}
  <div id="entry">
  {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="{text:Width}"/>{LinkCloseTag}
  {/block:Photo}

  {/block:Posts}

{block:IfEndlessScroll}
</div>
{/block:IfEndlessScroll}

{block:ifnotendlessscroll}
<div id="bottom">
  {block:Pagination}
  {block:NextPage}<div style="float:right; "><a href="{NextPage}">progress</a></div>{/block:NextPage}
  {block:PreviousPage}<div style="float:left"><a href="{PreviousPage}">regress</a></div>{/block:PreviousPage}
  {/block:Pagination}
</div>
{/block:ifnotendlessscroll}
```